# A Bluetooth keyboard fails to connect after a few seconds of being connected

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I am failing to connect my keyboard to my Ubuntu. The computer connects to the keyboard for a few seconds and then disconnects. These are the outputs of bluetoothctl. How can I troubleshoot this?

It looks like once connected but the keyboard is not working,

```
[bluetooth]# connect DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA
Attempting to connect to DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA RSSI: -59
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA Connected: yes
Connection successful
[Ergonomic Keyboard]#
```

Then it changes to this in a few seconds.

```
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA Connected: no
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA RSSI: -59
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA RSSI: -68
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA RSSI: -68
[CHG] Device DD:93:4C:4C:E7:AA RSSI: -59
```

My Ubuntu version is 22.04.2 LTS, the keyboard is Microsoft Surface Ergonomic Keyboard. The keyboard used to be connected but now keep producing this issue.

Comment: Try `echo "options btusb enable_autosuspend=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btusb.conf` and reboot

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion but it didn't work. After adding that line, I rebooted and tried to connect again but I get the output `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled` in the bluetoothctl. the keyboard is in pairing mode, has the light indicator, changed the battery too. Any other ideas to debug?